# How to retrieve and store data into a database?

Tags: database, angular

I've recently started working with Angular programming. I'm working on an application that has to be programmed with Angular.

I need to make a filtering/ search field on a website, where the user can search data, which will be retrieved from a database. The results of the search has to be stored back into a database/file. I'm not sure where I have to start and how to approach this. I appreciate some suggestions.

Edit: I've found some examples of how to read from database. But what I'm asking more specific is basically saving the retrieved data from the search into a new file/database.

Comment: you need to have backEnd Restful service which will be communicating  with your DB. You may consider to use Firebase if you don't want to create back-end service

Answer (score 2):

Angular is a **front-end** development framework. It means that it is just there to build the web interface for your application.

It does not store information in a persistent way, to a database or something because it only has direct access to the local browser on which it is run (it is just javascript that is being run after all).

To store persistent data, you need to build a **back-end** server. Your frontend Angular application asks for any information to show, sends request to update it depending on user interaction and so on. Your backend treats all these requests and uses a database to do its job.

Typically, your backend server will serve an API built on the REST standard. It can receive requests with data, and it will create/read/update/delete data (see `CRUD` acronym for more information on this concept).

Popular backend frameworks include [Ruby on Rails](https://rubyonrails.org/) (Ruby language), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (Python language) or [Nodejs](https://www.codementor.io/shanewignall/making-a-restful-backend-with-node-js-knf7nbsii).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great explanations.

Answer (score 1):

As another user pointed out, you need to have a backend service (REST usually) managing your database connection. How to go about this is outside of the scope of your question. Here is an overview of some database/data storage options.

For an application that will never be deployed to a production environment:

- SQLite database
- JSON file on disk (flush the changes to the file every time the data is changed in memory)

For applications where type enforcement is not important

- A document database such as MongoDB or Dynamo

For applications where you are just storing uploaded flat files

- Use a simple table in any DB to store the relationship between a user and files.
- Store the files in AWS S3

For an application that needs strong schema and production level robustness

- Postgresql, MySQL/MariaDB. These can be purchased as a service from AWS or Google Cloud Platform.

For all the technologies mentioned above, I am sure a google search will provide details on how to use them in the Angular environment. It is easy to fall into a flame war about databases and their various advantages and disadvantages. I have tried to keep things simple since it sounds like you are just getting started.